# c++ struct declaration collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Tags: c, struct, linker, g++

I managed to solve this issue, but I don't understand why this works like this, so I'm looking for only an clarification for this and any explanations are welcome.

I'm doing the excercises from Bruce Eckel's book: Thinking in C++.
Excercise 13 in Vol 1., Chapter 4 is creating "abstract data type that represents a videotape in a video rental store"
As per the topic of this chapter I assume this should be a struct, like this very simple one:

```
    //video.h
    typedef struct {
        unsigned id;
        char* title;
        float length;
        int inRent;

        void printout();
    } Video;
```

with a dummy implementation, like:

```
//video.cpp
#include "stdio.h"
#include "video.h"

void Video::printout(){     
    printf("id:%u, title:%s, length:%f\n",this->id,this->title,this->length); 
}
```

and with a main.cpp like this:

```
//main.cpp
#include "video.h"
#include "stdio.h"

int main(){

    Video first;

    first.id=1;
    first.title="Some title";
    first.length=1.5;

    first.printout();

    return 0;   
}
```

When trying to compile and link with `gcc -o main.exe main.cpp video.cpp -lstdc++`, I get this error below at linking. I get the same result with g++ too

```
C:\Users\jani\AppData\Local\Temp\cc1KIhpp.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x2e): undefined reference to `Video::printout()'
```

When I use struct identifier - like: `typedef struct some_id {...} Video;` - compiles and runs without error.

How does this struct declaration work in similar cases? 
Eckel says: "You’ll notice that the struct identifier has been left off at the beginning, because the goal is to create the typedef. However, there are times when you might need to refer to the struct during its definition. (...)".
In which cases does this apply?

Many thanks for the answers.

Janos

Comment: I don't think :: is valid for c, so isn't this a C++ question?

Comment: I assume the top is video.h, then video.cpp, then main.cpp?

Comment: yes, you are right. :: is not valid for C
However C++ linker produces the error.
" video.h, then video.cpp, then main.cpp?" - Yes you are right.

Comment: Please advise on typedef struct declaration, and do not bother with headers inclusion or compile/link order.
If you check, original question was why in the case "typedef struct" requires struct identifier for succesful linking.
In other words why can this be complied and linked: 
`typedef struct something {...} Video;`, and this why does this not work:
`typedef struct {...} Video;`

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you provide the stdio or iostream header in the video.cpp file..These headers provide dynamic linking according to you system. I f you do manual linking just from a simple Makefile, it may not be os & hardware independent.

More importantly, you are not using any C/C++ library functions in the main file, so no need to include stdio.h in the main. Rather include it video.c file

Comment: "Why don't you provide the stdio or iostream header in the video.cpp file" - It's already there!
"so no need to include stdio.h in the main. Rather include it video.c file" - I tried this too, however results the same linker error

Comment: First make them a .c file not .cpp..Then write #include <stdio.h> in video.c file not "stdio.h"..It is giving linker error because it is probably assuming that you have the header in the present working directory which is not true..

Comment: compile it without any linker option..More importantly you cannot create any function in the structure if it is C..If you want to stick to c++ strictly, then remove all the "stdio.h" & include <iostream> & in place of printf in video.c file, use std::cout..Use either C or C++

Comment: Thanks! I decided to rewrite it pure C++, and that may solve.

Answer (score 1):

you should compile with g++ (no need to link libstdc++ since all commonly available linux distributions will use libstdc++ by default) and the correct syntax for declaring struct in cpp is:

```
struct Video
{
  std::string title; // note that you used char* for title and assigned it a string literal which is of type const char*, there is no implicit conversion for that.
  ...
};
```

Also instead of printf you should use iostream for formatted output, it's more efficient, less error prone and more readable:

```
#include <iostream>

void Video::printout(){     
  std::cout << this->id << this->title << this->length << std::endl; 
}
```

Comment: Yes Anna, you are right. In paralell, I`m alos testing differences between C and C++ compilers, so that's why I'm intentianally using printf fuction to be able to compile with both.

Comment: Sorry, your other suggestion does not work:
`d:\playground\CPPpractice>g++ -o main.exe video.cpp main.cpp video.cpp
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:5:8: error: expected ';' before 'first'
  Video first;
        ^
main.cpp:7:2: error: 'first' was not declared in this scope
  first.id=1;
  ^`

Comment: have you included your video.h in main.cpp? xD

Answer (score 0):

It is just a matter of linking order.  The following should work:

```
g++ -o main.exe video.cpp main.cpp -lstdc++
```

or (for the paranoid):

```
g++ -o main.exe video.cpp main.cpp video.cpp -lstdc++
```

Comment: Thanks, but both suggestions result the same linker error here.

Comment: oops, right, I think it is technically C++.  (The confusion of which language you are using might be relevant.)

Comment: Already tried that one too: 
`(d:\playground\CPPpractice>g++ -o main.exe video.cpp main.cpp video.cpp -lstdc++
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
C:\Users\jani\AppData\Local\Temp\cc3coLCU.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x2e): undefined reference to Video::printout()'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status)`